# Find usb device name to unmount/eject

Tags: usb, mount

I have a canon camera plugged into the usb of my Pi.  I want to unmount or eject  it but I dont know how to find the device name to supply to the unmount or eject command.  lsblk gives the following and not the /dev/sda paths

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsblk
NAME        MAJ:MIN RM  SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
mmcblk0     179:0    0 59.6G  0 disk 
├─mmcblk0p1 179:1    0  1.8G  0 part 
├─mmcblk0p2 179:2    0    1K  0 part 
├─mmcblk0p5 179:5    0   32M  0 part /media/pi/SETTINGS7
├─mmcblk0p6 179:6    0   69M  0 part /boot
└─mmcblk0p7 179:7    0 56.4G  0 part /
```

lsusb shows it on 7

```
pi@raspberrypi:~ $ lsusb
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 1c4f:0002 SiGma Micro Keyboard TRACER Gamma Ivory
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 045e:0040 Microsoft Corp. Wheel Mouse Optical
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 16d0:063d MCS 
Bus 001 Device 007: ID 04a9:30fc Canon, Inc. PowerShot A620 (PTP mode)
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:ec00 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMSC9512/9514 Fast Ethernet Adapter
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0424:9514 Standard Microsystems Corp. SMC9514 Hub
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the column labeled `MOUNTPOINT`. `lsblk` shows your camera is not mounted. It shows the ***only*** mounted device partitions are on your SD card. `lsusb` has nothing to do with "mounting", it concerns itself only with devices on the bus.

Try this experiment to prove it to yourself:

- run `lsblk -fs`
- insert a thumb drive in one of the USB ports
- run `lsblk -fs` again

You'll see the thumb drive listed as `sda` (or `sdb`, or whatever), but there will be NO MOUNTPOINT in the output.

Comment: unfortuantly u are right i didnt understand what is going on but now i do

Comment: @bakalolo: It's easy to get confused :) I've noticed this on my Canon cameras also... they (apparently) don't provide direct access to the media in the camera, instead requiring that you access the media through a software layer. I feel this is a "good thing" - corrupting a device with 2,000 RAW image files could be a headache! You also mentioned the `eject` command, and that caused me to wonder about some things. Outside the *nix world, unmount or `umount` are unknown. Apple & MS use the term "eject" as it makes more sense to more people. But this does lead to some confusion - for many of us!

Answer (score 1):

Which camera model do you have?  Most "newer" cameras no longer connect to the computer as a "mass storage device".  A "mass storage device" is typically "owned" by one controller.  In other words... when mounted by the computer, it cannot be used by the "camera" because the computer wants exclusive block level access to the file system.

The advantage of protocols such as PTP (Picture Transfer Protocol) is that it's a logical protocol that ignores the notion of a block-storage device with an exclusive owner.  This means that while the computer is transferring images from the camera, the camera can *continue* to capture more images (more than one device can use the memory card).

If this is true of *your* camera model (some cameras let you set which mode should be used, but few "newer" cameras offer the choice) is that there is no mass-storage device to "eject".

Rather than connecting the "camera" via a connection cable (e.g. USB) you can remove the memory card and attach it to a memory card reader inserted into the Raspberry Pi.  If you use this approach, then the memory card will be mounted as a mass-storage device (typically the mount point shows up under the /media path).

Comment: THis is an old camera powershot a620(~ 2005).  I need to eject it to let gphoto2 have access to it.

Answer (score 1):

You are using `lsblk` to find mounted devices. But `lsblk` is doing what its name says: it only lists block devices like hard disks or SD Cards. But the USB connection of your camera isn't seen as block device. Try to use

```
rpi ~$ findmnt
```

Comment: I'd not used `findmnt` until I read your answer. It's useful, but just out of curiosity, do you feel it's better than `lsusb` for learning details on connected USB devices?

Comment: @Seamus The question was about finding usb device name to unmount/eject. So you have to look how it is mounted. `lsusb` will not give you any information about mounting.

Comment: But it wasn't mounted according to `lsblk` output. `lsblk` showed there were no block storage devices other than the SD card mounted or connected. AFAIK, `eject` is only useful for CD/DVD devices... I'm of the opinion it doesn't accomplish much on flash memory devices - am I wrong?

Comment: @Seamus You are right with `eject` but the OP wants to *unmount or eject* his cannon camera and therefore he is looking for the **device name**. You find it neither with `lsblk` nor with `lsusb`. My cannon camera does mount with a pseudo filesystem **GPhotoFS**. It is a filesystem client based on libgphoto2 that exposes supported cameras as filesystems (similar to `/dev` or `/sys`). So I think you will only find the device name with `mount` or `findmnt` to unmount it with `fusermount -u /mnt/mountlocation` https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/402504/243074

Comment: And the advantage of that is...? IoW, if it's not a mounted filesystem, then there is no reason not to just "pull the plug" - is there?  oh, +1 BTW - this is v. helpful IMO.

Comment: @Seamus I don't get your point. Before unplug the USB cable the cannon is connected to the RasPi you should do a clean unmount of the device name, otherwise you risk to corrupt just copied photos.

Comment: I don't see how one could corrupt the photos. The camera has a battery, and its software is responsible for maintaining the integrity of the files on its media card. Granted, if you're xferring files to your PC one of those might be corrupted, but I would assume one would watch the app on his PC & avoid that. And - what will the camera's software do about it?